# api call on init and params change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, rxjs

I am attempting to make an api call based on params using angular2. I need to make this api call when the component is initialized and when the params change. Below is the code I am using. The problem is when `ngOnInit` is run it calls the api with the params and then immediately subscribes to changes which calls the api 2 more times.

What is the proper way to handle this sort of situation so that the api call is only called once on init while still being able to observe changes to the params?

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.zip(this.route.queryParams, this.route.params).subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.queryParams = params[0];
    this.params = params[1];
    this.get();
    this.subscribe();
  });
}

subscribe() {
  this.queryParamsSub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.queryParams = params;
    this.get();
  });

  this.paramsSub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.params = params;
    this.get();
  });
}

// this is called 3 times on init
get() {
  this.apiManager.get(this.queryParams, this.params);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.queryParamsSub.unsubscribe();
  this.paramsSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: What about setting an "init-flag" which prevents initally the two get() calls inside the subscribe()-function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can use `Observable.combineLatest` to combine the observables and this will trigger on every change. Something like this works nicely:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = Observable.combineLatest(this.route.queryParams, this.route.params).subscribe((params: any) => {
      this.queryParams = params[0];
      this.params = params[1];
      this.get();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

isn't the `ngOnInit` enough (without the call to `subscribe`)? You are already subscribed to the changes with `zip`. Why would you resubscribe again? Or I miss something obvious?

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.zip(this.route.queryParams, this.route.params).subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.queryParams = params[0];
    this.params = params[1];
    this.get();
  });
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately zip only gets called once.